# Find angle a path makes with the horizontal given magnitude and angle made with other paths.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, partial-derivative

Given this information:

"The elevation along a straight path up the side of a hill increases at a rate of 1/3 meter per horizontal meter. At point P, a new path at an angle of /6 with the original path goes off more steeply uphill. The steepest uphill direction at P makes an angle of /3 with the original path."

"What angle does the new path make with the horizontal?"

It seems to be a standard directional derivative and gradient question, but I can't seem to get any definitive answer, because no direction of the original path or the new path/steepest path is given. For example, it seems valid to say the original path is along x-axis, in which case the horizontal angle would be /6 , or I could have the original path be have an angle 5/6 with the x-axis, in which case it seems my new path would have a horizontal angle of /2.

I'm either misunderstanding the question and visualizing it wrong, or I need more information. Anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: The angle of the first path (before point $P$) is $\arctan(1/3)$

Comment: Won't that just me get the angle of elevation in 3-space? How does that relate to the angle the path in the x-y plane makes with the horizontal axis?

Comment: The problem doesn't mention any coordinate system, so when I say the angle of the first path is $\arctan(1/3)$, this is the angle with respect to the bottom of the hill.

Comment: I assumed the path was being projected into the x-y plane. What exactly does the horizontal refer to in general?

Comment: Let me provide you with a graph to help you understand these terms. One moment.

Comment: The black line in this graph is the horizontal. You can move around $v_1$ and $v_2$ to determine the direction of upward motion on the hill. The point where all three of these vectors meet is the point $P$. https://www.math3d.org/GlsympVr

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you, it seems we need one more information, that is the maximum slope for the new path.

I'm assuming that the angle of $/6$ for the new path direction  with the original path and the angle of $/3$ for the steepest uphill direction at P with the original path are both evaluated projecting the two paths direction in the horizontal plane.